# Save File Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, pickle, shelve

So for my intro programming class we have to create a game with a save/load function and I'm trying to test out some code to make sure it works.

For some reason I cannot get the following function to work properly. I've tried going through it line by line in the Idle and it works just fine there but once I try to use the same system in a function it just will not work. Help please?

```
def save(name,inventory,mapGrid,x,y,enemy):`

    choice = 0

    file = shelve.open("save_files")       
    save = {'save1':file['save1'],'save2':file['save2'],'save3':file['save3']}

    print("Where would you like to save?")
    print("Save 1 -", save['save1']['name'])
    print("Save 2 -", save['save2']['name'])
    print("Save 3 -", save['save3']['name'])
    choice = input("Enter Number:\t")

    if choice == 1:
        save['save1']['name'] = name
        save['save1']['inventory'] = inventory
        save['save1']['mapGrid'] = mapGrid
        save['save1']['x'] = x
        save['save1']['y'] = y
        save['save1']['enemy'] = enemy
        file['save1'] = save['save1']
        file.sync()
    if choice == 2:
        save['save2']['name'] = name
        save['save2']['inventory'] = inventory
        save['save2']['mapGrid'] = mapGrid
        save['save2']['x'] = x
        save['save2']['y'] = y
        save['save2']['enemy'] = enemy
        file['save2'] = save['save2']
        file.sync()
    if choice == 3:
        save['save3']['name'] = name
        save['save3']['inventory'] = inventory
        save['save3']['mapGrid'] = mapGrid
        save['save3']['x'] = x
        save['save3']['y'] = y
        save['save3']['enemy'] = enemy
        file['save3'] = save['save3']
        file.sync()

    file.close()

    print("Game Saved")
```

EDIT: After running the function it should save the dictionary to file['save#'] and allow me to access the data later on, but the data doesn't save to the shelve file and when I try to access it again there's nothing there. ((Sorry should have put this in right off the bat))

For example if I run the save() function again it should display the name associated with the save file, but it just shows 'EMPTY'.

The basic thing I have the save_files set to is

file['save#'] = {'name':'EMPTY'}

Comment: How does it not work? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: You should update the post with the error messages etc you get, and what the expected output would be. Check [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: After running the function it should save the dictionary to file['save#'] and allow me to access the data later on, but the data doesn't save to the shelve file and when I try to access it again there's nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `if` statements are comparing `int`, make sure that `choice` is also an integer. It's possible that `choice` is actually a string, in which case none of the comparisons will be True. Basically:

```
choice = int(input("Enter Number:\t"))
```

Alternatively you could change all comparisons to strings, but the important thing is to assure type consistency in the comparisons